# Optimize recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, optimization

I've got a problem. I have a highly recursive function, which will take years to execute as the datasets become increasingly larger. Do you have an idea, how to optimize it, so it might run in a few minutes?

```
DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate = {}
        for Daten in DatenListeE124:
            if Daten[0] not in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate.keys():
                DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Daten[0]] = []
            DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Daten[0]].append(Daten)    
DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandateTabelle = []
        # Durschnitt bilden aus der neuen Tabelle
        Jahre = list(range(datetime.datetime.now().year-(FormularHochladen.Jahre.data-1), datetime.datetime.now().year+1))
        for Schluessel in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate.keys():
            for Daten in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
                for Daten2 in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
                    for Daten3 in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
                        if Daten[3] == Daten2[3] == Daten3[3] and Daten[2] == Daten2[2] + 1 == Daten3[2] + 2 and Daten[2] in Jahre:
                            DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandateTabelle.append([Daten[0], Daten[1], f"{Daten[2]}, {Daten2[2]}, {Daten3[2]}", Daten[3], round((Daten[4]+Daten2[4]+Daten3[4])/3, 2), round((Daten[5]+Daten2[5]+Daten3[5])/3, 2), round((Daten[6]+Daten2[6]+Daten3[6])/3, 2), round((Daten[7]+Daten2[7]+Daten3[7])/3, 2), round((Daten[8]+Daten2[8]+Daten3[8])/3, 2)])
```

Democontent of the lists:

```
    Jahre = [2019, 2020, 2021]
    DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate = {10021: [[10021, 'Max, Mustermann', 2012, 35, 694.9, 523.9, 171.0, 3.0, 174.63], [10021, 'Max, Mustermann', 2013, 35, 794.1, 627.86, 166.24, 3.0, 209.29]], 10025: [[10025, 'Max Mustermann 2', 2013, 98, 5.8, 5.8, 0, 0, -1]], 10026: [[10026, 'Max Mustermann 3', 2012, 24, 300.9, 300.9, 0, 0, -1], [10026, 'Max Mustermann 3', 2012, 35, 999, 695, 304, 4, 173.75]], 10027: [[10027, 'Max Mustermann 4', 2014, 35, 574.95, 291.95, 283, 5.08, 57.43]]}
    DatenListeE124 = [[10021, 'Max, Mustermann 1', 2012, 35, 694.9, 523.9, 171.0, 3.0, 174.63], [10021, 'Max, Mustermann 1', 2013, 35, 794.1, 627.86, 166.24, 3.0, 209.29], [10025, 'Max, Mustermann 2', 2013, 98, 5.8, 5.8, 0, 0, -1], [10026, 'Max, Mustermann 3', 2012, 24, 300.9, 300.9, 0, 0, -1], [10026, 'Max, Mustermann 3', 2012, 35, 999, 695, 304, 4, 173.75], [10027, 'Max, Mustermann 4', 2014, 35, 574.95, 291.95, 283, 5.08, 57.43], [10030, 'Max, Mustermann 5', 2015, 33, 670, 98.6, 571.4, 12.02, 8.21], [10032, 'Max, Mustermann 6', 2018, 21, 180, 148.5, 31.5, 0.5, 297.0]]
```

And maybe even more memory-saving?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not see any recursive functions in sample you posted.

Comment: Is it a homework question?

In general avoid deeply nested loops.

In your specific example you perform a certain operation for every set of 3 elements out of array. The complexity of this operation is cubic as there are N ways to select one element so N^3 to pick 3.

Please explain what you tried to achieve.

The elements inside your array should probably be objects with properly named fields.

You should avoid using non English words in your variables. I saw production code with function names in Hebrew and Russian and it was not nice.

Comment: No, it isn't - but thanks for your hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution somebody else pointed out was to use:
'''
itertools.product(DatenListeE124_Durchschnitt[Schlüssel], repeat=3)'''
which works really nice and fast!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, your problem is the tripe loop here...

```
for Daten in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
  for Daten2 in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
    for Daten3 in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
      if Daten[3] == Daten2[3] == Daten3[3] and Daten[2] == Daten2[2] + 1 == Daten3[2] + 2 and Daten[2] in Jahre:
         ...
```

You should not to iterate `DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]` in a triple loop. So ideas are:

- The best you can do is to use two dictionaries to index elements by its `Daten[2]` and `Daten[3]` values. Then iterate only elements that will comply the condition in the last line
- A easier improvement is to prune the search as soon as you can, for example:

```
for Daten in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
    if Daten[2] in Jahre:
      for Daten2 in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
        if Daten[3] == Daten2[3] and Daten[2] == Daten2[2] + 1:
          for Daten3 in DatenListeE124_DurchschnittMandate[Schluessel]:
            if Daten[3] == Daten3[3] and Daten[2] == Daten3[2] + 2 :
         ...
```

Comment: That helped me really!